# Get the name of iteration in purrr::map function

Tags: r, plot, purrr, gam

I am making graphs from 4 statistical models subsetting "virus" variable. I don't know how to put the title of the graphs according to "virus" variable.

I made this reproducible set:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(lubridate)
library(mgcv)
library(purrr)


set.limpio <- data.frame(Codigo= 1:1000, Dia = rnorm(1000,100,2),
                     R = rbinom(1000,1,.5),
                    virus = c(rep("V1",250),
                              rep("V2",250),
                              rep("V3",250),
                              rep("V4",250)))
plots <- set.limpio %>% 
  filter(.$Dia < 250) %>%
  split(.$virus) %>%
  map(~ gam(R ~ s(Dia) + s(Codigo, bs = "re"), data = ., 
            family = binomial(link = "logit"), method = "REML")) %>% 
  map( ~ plot.gam(.,shade = T, scale = 0, scheme = 3,
                  xlab = "Days",
                  ylab = "Positivity"))
```

In this section should be the title

```
map( ~ plot.gam(.,shade = T, scale = 0,scheme = 3,xlab = "Days", ylab = 
    "Positivity", main = "here should be the title"))
```

I tried:

```
main = paste(names(.))
```

also with

```
deparse(substitute(obj))
```

But none of them worked.

This is how I want the graphs. That should be the result of the first graph out of the four remaining.
[image]

Comment: Try `imap`. Take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51966038/generate-n-ggplot-plots-by-passing-a-wrapper-a-set-of-params-in-r/51966199#51966199).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As markus commented, you can use `imap`.

```
plots <- set.limpio %>% 
  filter(.$Dia < 250) %>%
 split(.$virus) %>%
  map(~ gam(R ~ s(Dia) + s(Codigo, bs="re"), data = ., 
          family = binomial(link = "logit"), method="REML")) %>% 
  imap( ~ plot.gam(.,shade = T, scale = 0,scheme = 3,xlab = "Days", ylab = 
"Positivity", main= .y))
```

I just replaced the second `map` call with `imap` and added parameter `main = .y`

If the goal is just to display plots (`plot.gam` doesn't return plot objects), then you should use `iwalk` instead and you have no need to assign it to `plots` to make it silent.

see `?imap`